# Force Close when process Intent from ListFragment to new Activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

```
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): Process: com.faprojekt, PID: 1366
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.faprojekt/com.faprojekt.page.PengantarDetailPage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:849)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:907)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:916)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.faprojekt.page.ActPengantar.goClickContentDetail(ActPengantar.java:109)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.faprojekt.page.ActPengantar.onListItemClick(ActPengantar.java:73)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
02-11 12:55:13.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

Comment: It says `ActivityNotFoundException` have you declared Activity `PengantarDetailPage` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Before I want to say thanks you for your comment on my post question. I have get solution with my problem, it forgot to declare as package name on manifest

Old:
android:name=".PengantarDetailPage"

New:
android:name="com.example.site.PengantarDetailPage"

and I change extends in my class, from Fragment to AppCompatActivity

Comment: No problem. Glad to know you have solved your problem.